# Access VBA code in Form_current updating previous record, not current

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to write a value to a record as soon as it is pulled into the form in Access.  I put the code into the Form_current event code, thinking this would work, but I am getting an unexpected result.  It is writing to the previous record.   So for example if I go from record A to record B, it will write the values to the fields in record A. Oddly, if I have a message box display the value of the field it will display the value from record B, though. It is very simple code, but here is what I have.   I tried the RefreshRecord and DoEvents, because i thought they might help, but they did not.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
Dim username As String

username = Right(Environ("USERPROFILE"), Len(Environ("USERPROFILE")) - InStrRev(Environ("USERPROFILE"), "\")) 'Removes path and keeps the Novell ID

DoCmd.RefreshRecord
DoEvents

Me.Record_lock = vbTrue
Me.Locked_by = username


End Sub
```

Any help on this would be appreciated.  I have worked with VBA before in Excel, but never really in Access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Form_Current` can fire repeatedly while the form is open ... not just once when the form is first opened.

From the *Form.Current Event* help topic ...

> Occurs when the focus moves to a record, making it the current record,
>   or when the form is refreshed or requeried.

So with your code, it's not surprising that you have updated `Record_lock` and `Locked_by` values for record A after you navigate away from record A to record B.

At that point, record B has become the "current record", so it should have those updated values, too.  You confirmed that point with `MsgBox`.  However, the changes to that record may not have yet been saved, which means you would not see them in the source table yet.

If the remaining issue is that you're not seeing the updated record B values displayed in the form, add `Me.Refresh` on a separate line before `End Sub`.

Comment: Record B was not showing as updated, which is what I was confused by.  Your suggesting to Refresh after the update worked like a charm.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to comment first, but I am a new user. Have you tried refreshing the record, before modifying the field?

Comment: I did, but I did not refresh after, which as HansUp pointed out, was the correct answer.  Thank you for trying to help though.   Much appreciated.